# MS Word change background color with macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can I change the background color of the page in Microsoft Word 2003 (2007, 2010, 2013) through a macro?

I am attempting to create a Word macro (Microsoft Word 2013) to change the page background color. I began by recording the keystrokes - this is the recorded macro:

```
Sub WritingLayout() 
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 204)    
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Transparency = 0#     
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureParchment     
End Sub
```

This macro does not work on new documents.

Comment: Which background do you mean? The page itself?

Comment: Whatever the background he's speaking about, the standard way to discover it is to use the macro recorder, do the action to automatize "by hand", and then to adapt & clean the resulting code.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Except that the macro recorder has become very "spotty" in what it records as Microsoft has not maintained it well for newer functionality (graphics, especially). So before we can recommend the macro recorder we do have to know more...

Comment: Never had problems, but if you had, you're probably right. Anyways, I was not clear enough, I see;  the recorder is a starting point. Never ever use its result raw. It needs intense reworking, whatever happens.

Comment: I am attempting to create a Word macro (Microsoft Word 2013) to change the page background color. I began by recording the keystrokes - this is the recorded macro:
---
Sub WritingLayout()
'
' Macro
'
   ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 204)
   ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Transparency = 0#
   ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureParchment
End Sub
---
This macro does not work on new documents.

Answer (score 5):

I found how to do it. Just add this line before the vba code:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True
```

Here is the entire macro:

```
Sub WritingLayout()
'
' WritingLayout Macro
'
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Transparency = 0#
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureParchment
End Sub
```